# problem with data in a while loop in java

Tags: java, while-loop

running this code, I am unable to have the number add properly. it only adds the data from the last loop

```
public class P4_3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your 8 digit Credit Card Number ");
        String cardNumber = in.next();

        if (cardNumber.length() == 8)
        {
            int totalFirst = 0;
            int currentIndex = cardNumber.length() - 1;
            int secondIndex = cardNumber.length() -2;
            int secondDouble = 0;
            String collectDigit;
            int digitSecond = 0;
            int digitFirst = 0;
            int totalDigit = 0;

            while (currentIndex >= 0)
            {       
                int smallValue = Character.digit(cardNumber.charAt(currentIndex), 10);
                totalFirst = totalFirst + smallValue;
                currentIndex = currentIndex - 2;
                int secondValue = Character.digit(cardNumber.charAt(secondIndex), 10);
                secondDouble = secondValue * 2;
                secondIndex = secondIndex - 2;
                System.out.println("second double " + secondDouble);
                collectDigit = Integer.toString(secondDouble);

                if (collectDigit.length() == 2)
                {
                    digitFirst = Character.digit(collectDigit.charAt(0), 10);
                    digitSecond = Character.digit(collectDigit.charAt(1), 10);
                    totalDigit = digitFirst + digitSecond;
                    System.out.println("First digit " + digitFirst);
                    System.out.println("Second digit " + digitSecond);
                }
                else 
                {
                    digitFirst = Character.digit(collectDigit.charAt(0), 10);
                    totalDigit = digitFirst;
                }        
            }

            int checkNumber = totalDigit + totalFirst;
            System.out.println("Card check number = " + checkNumber);

            if (checkNumber % 5 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("The final digit of Check number is 0" + checkNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The credit card number is not valid " + checkNumber);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Credit Card number not correct length");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your code or its formatting, I see only one loop.

Comment: What is "currentIndex"? If it is 0 then the loop is only executed once because after this currentIndex is -2 and the loop condition is false then.

Comment: sorry, I updated the code now

Comment: Well, it's a given that the code isn't doing what you think it's doing. The best advice you could get, in my opinion, is to identify the individual logical steps involved in this validation and make a method that represents each step. Implement each method and test each part individually. Errors in your program logic should then become much more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

OK your updated code is a little tricky to follow (even with proper formatting), but if I understand what it is trying to do here is a easier way to accomplish this might be (and I'm abusing RuntimeExceptions here):

```
public class P4_3_simple {
  public static int checkNumber(String cardNumber) {
    int size = cardNumber.length();
    int sum_firsts = 0;
    int sum_seconds = 0;

    if(size == 8) {
      for(int index = 7; index >= 0; index -= 2) {
        int first = Character.digit(cardNumber.charAt(index), 10);
        int second = Character.digit(cardNumber.charAt(index - 1), 10) * 2;
        sum_firsts += first;
        sum_seconds += addDigits(second);
      }
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("Credit Card number not correct length");
    }

    return sum_firsts + sum_seconds;
  }

  public static int addDigits(int value) {
    int reduced = value;
    if(reduced > 9) {
      reduced = 0;
      char[] digits = Integer.toString(value, 10).toCharArray();
      for(char digit : digits) {
        reduced += Character.digit(digit, 10);
      }
    }

    return reduced;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your 8 digit Credit Card Number ");
    int checkNumber = checkNumber(in.next());
    System.out.println("Card check number = " + checkNumber);
    if (checkNumber % 5 == 0) {
      System.out.println("The final digit of Check number is 0" + checkNumber);
    } else {
      System.out.println("The credit card number is not valid " + checkNumber);
    }
  }
}
```

A test of 13345678 returns a valid credit card (with a check sum of 35).  As for where your code went wrong it looks like your assignments of totalDigit are resetting it's value to the last executed loop.  I'm assuming of course that that is what you are referring to when you say only the last sum is added.  If I'm wrong about that you could change my code and get the exact same behavior as you code (just with fewer global vars)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what value `currentIndex` is starting at, but if it's 0 or 1 then the first iteration through the loop will set it into negative territory, and your `while` condition demands for it to be greater than or equal to 0.

In brief, if `currentIndex` starts at 0 or 1, you'll only get one iteration before the program exits the loop.

Comment: You can't post code blocks in comments. It's best to edit your question.